# Getting Keras repeat_elements to work inside custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, tensor

I am trying to create a Keras custom loss function (RankOpt, from http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.2.3727&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

This is a binary classification loss function for a situation where false observations heavily outweight true; y_true will have a few ones in it and a bunch of zeroes. Long story short, I want to extract the preds for which y_true is 1 into a vector, and repeat that vector end to end until the result is as long as the preds for which y_true is zero.

This will give me 2 equal length vectors (ok, 1d tensors), of length equal to the number of zeros in y_true, which I then process pairwise. The left hand vector/tensor consists of predictions which were actually True, repeated sufficiently to reach the length of those which were actually False.

The whole thing is differentiable AFAICS so should in theory be ok, but I'm struggling to coerce Keras to like it.

I've managed to get this far:

```
def AUC_proxy(y_true, y_pred):
    mask1 = y_true >= 1
    mask0 = y_true <= 0
    pred1 = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask1)
    pred0 = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask0)
    len1 = K.shape(pred1)[0]
    len0 = K.shape(pred0)[0]
    ratio = len0 // len1
    rem = len0 % len1

    pred1reps = K.repeat_elements(pred1, ratio, 0)
    if (rem != 0) :
        K.concatenate(pred1reps, pred1[0:rem])

    return K.sum(K.sigmoid(pred1reps - pred0)) / (len1 + len0)
```

But, Keras complains that the first parameter of repeat_elements must have a known shape up front AFAICS:

`ValueError: Axis 0 of input tensor should have a defined dimension, but is None. Full tensor shape: (None,). Typically you need to pass a fully-defined`input_shape`argument to your first layer.`

Is there any way to get around this? Looks like I can get the predictions for True and False, it's the repetition of the Trues to line up with the False that's the tricky part.

I have also tried using tensorflow while_loop, without success.

Comment: You could try a class "weight" approach: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

Comment: I have a baseline model using class weights and standard cross entropy loss, but want something which is a more accurate proxy for the AUC metric if I can.